# TYPO3: Installing Backend Languages manually

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to install backend languages for TYPO3 (Version 6.0) manually (without connectivity to the repository)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. You *should be able* to download translated language files (in XLIFF format) from the [TYPO3 translation server](http://translation.typo3.org/) and manually depoly them in your `typo3conf/l10n/<languagekey>` directory.

Alternatively, you can just set up a second TYPO3 instance, download the translation files from repository, and just deploy the entire `typo3conf/l10n` directory to your other site.